# Why do I have to round this value again?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using ajax to generate prices of books as quantities increase. The only problem I have was when I tried to generate total (see JS code) and it caused some problems (the values would concatenate instead of add). I solved the problem by rounding variable 'amount'. But I'm trying to understand why the concatenating happened. Here's my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_GET["amount1"]) )
{
    $amount1 = $_GET["amount1"];

    $error="";

    if($amount1 == "" || !preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $amount1))
    {
        $error .= "Please enter a valid number";
        echo $error;
    }
    else{
        echo round($amount1*16.65, 2);
    }
}
```

And this is the JS code:

```
      if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4)
      {
        var res = xhr.responseText;

        if(res.match(/\d+/)== null){
            document.getElementById("err3").innerHTML = res;
            document.getElementById("book3").innerHTML = "";
            total(0,3);
        }

        else{
            document.getElementById("book3").innerHTML = res;
            document.getElementById("err3").innerHTML = "";
            total(res,3);
          }
      }


var book1 = 0;
var book2 = 0;
var book3 = 0;

function total(amount, book)
{   
// amount = Math.round(amount*100)/100; --> this is what solved it but I don't    
 //know why I need it since amount was rounded by PHP code
if( book == 1)
    book1 = amount;

if( book == 2)
    book2 = amount;

if( book == 3)
    book3 = amount;

var total = book1 + book2 + book3;

document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`res` is text. Convert it to a number before using.

```
js> parseFloat("3.14")
3.14
```

Comment: Obviously much more to the point. Just as a quick note, using `Number()` would set the string to either int or float, depending on the string, while parse float will round off to the int value but hold the extra memory as a float.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it's concatenating is because the `+` operator is used for both string concatenation and adding, which drives me crazy. But more specifically, it's because values entered into a input field or passed to the browser from the server without some kind of wrapper (json or xml) are always handled as strings by javascript, and, unlike PHP, javascript does not support type juggling (at least not between numbers and strings).

Since this is being sent back from php via ajax, and since php is handling the number validation, you really just need to return the value in json format and update the javascript to use the returned object, like so:

First, the PHP, with slight tweak on validation:

```
// 1. Using ctype_digit function to confirm value is >= 0. Much faster than regex
// 2. No need to round, as integer * float is always same or less precision, and
//    PHP sets product to appropriate numeric type.
// 3. Pushing values into array for json encoding
// 4. Setting both values (empty if invalid) so that javascript can easily confirm
//    response.
// 5. Updated Error, as negative numbers and floats are valid, 
//    just not in this case

$amount1 = $_GET["amount1"]);
$response["amount1"] = (ctype_digit($amount1)) ? $amount1 * 16.65 : "";
$response["error"] = (ctype_digit($amount1)) ? "" : "Please enter a valid quantity";

echo json_encode($response);
```

Now, the javascript has to de-serialize the response string into an object, using `eval()`, and get the total and whatnot:

The javascript (again, some minor tweaks, this time without notes)

```
if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4)
{
    var res = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"); 

    amount1 = (!isNaN(res.amount1)) ? res.amount1 : "";     

    document.getElementById("err3").innerHTML = res.error;
    document.getElementById("book3").innerHTML = res.amount1;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total(Number(res.amount1),3);
}

var book1 = 0;
var book2 = 0;
var book3 = 0;

function total(amount, book)
{
switch (book) {
   case 1:
      book1 = amount;
      break;
   case 2:
      book2 = amount;
      break;
   case 3:
      book3 = amount;
      break;
}

return book1 + book2 + book3;
}
```

Now, you'll probably notice that when I finally pass the amount1 value to the `total` function, I actually wrapped it in the `Number()` function, which pretty much solves the issue without using JSON. In theory, I don't need to do this, if the PHP always returns a numeric value.  Here are the reasons I cast it to a Number type, in spite of this:

1. Because js doesn't do type juggling for numbers, this is just a good idea. You never know what PHP might return on a bad day, and validation should happen at both ends of communication.
2. This allows PHP to return an empty string for the value, which you can output to the user, and then `Number()` will set the empty string to `0` for the total function.
3. If you decide to skip the ajax method and do the pricing calculation browser-side, you'll have to always cast the value using `Number()`, so it's a good (albeit annoying) habit to get in to when dealing with numeric values from any outside source.

I'll post a jsfiddle in a few with a final version of how I would approach your overall goal, which you can disregard or steal, I just feel up to doing it.